# python program to expand a number in to prime factors

Tags: python, discrete-mathematics, prime-factoring

## there is some glitch in my code

### pls make it better

```
def factors (num):
    #num =  int( eval(input ("enter a number : ") ))

    to = (num//2)+2
    dict = []

    for a in range(2,to):
        for b in range (2,a+1):
            if num % b == 0:
                dict.append(b)
                num = num // b

    print (dict)

factors(2*2*2*2*2*2*2*2*2*2*2*2*2)
```

**desired outcome is**

```
[2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2]
```

but I an getting something like this

```
[2, 2, 2, 4, 2, 4, 2, 4, 2, 2]
```

Comment: Try using [Eratosphene Sieve](https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-program-for-sieve-of-eratosthenes/amp/) for prime factors selection. It is actually a lot faster for large numbers. And for small ones - I don't think execution time is that sufficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def factors(num):
    d = []
    while num > 1:
        for a in range(2, num+1):
            if num % a == 0:
                d.append(a)
                num = num // a
                break
    print(d)


factors(2 ** 14) # [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2]
```

Comment: thank you very much ☺️ it is working fine . I'll study the code and improve myself....